# in Emacs, how to search filenames in fixed set of directories?

Tags: emacs, grep, emacs-helm

In Emacs, is there a mode or function that will allow me to search for a string within the filenames (but not within the files) in a fixed set of non-contiguous directories that I have specified in advance?

I believe `projectile-mode` allows me to search for filenames within a project, but I believe a project is defined as a directory containing files. I would need to search in several disparate directories.

Answer (score 2):

Library [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) can help with this.

1. In *Icicle* mode, all commands, including file-finding (visiting) commands, let you act on multiple input patterns at the same time.  For example, to visit all files in directory `/a/b/c` whose names match Unix/Linux glob pattern `foo*.el`, plus all files in dir `/x/y` whose names match glob pattern `bar*toto*.c`, you can do this:

   > > ```
   > >  C-x C-f /a/b/c/foo*.el /x/y/bar*toto*.c M-R
   > > ```

   The `M-R` is what causes your minibuffer input to be parsed as multiple file-name patterns.  (If you need a pattern that matches file names with spaces then enclose the pattern with `"..."`.)

   See [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#FirstExampleMultiInputs) page, which describes this simple multi-input feature.
2. You can *create a set of file names to reuse later*, including persistently (i.e., reuse in another Emacs session).  [***This page***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets) describes this feature.

   To do this, after `C-x C-f` you type a file-name pattern that matches some of the files you want (e.g. in a particular directory), then hit `TAB` or `S-TAB` to complete the pattern (and show the matches in popup window `*Completions*`), and then you hit `C-M->` (or `C-u C-M->` to save persistently).

   The patterns here are not glob patterns -- you are not passing them to the shell.  They are Emacs Lisp regexps, or substring patterns, or prefix patterns, or fuzzy-matching patterns,...  In general, regexps are your friends here.

   Using `C-M->` *marks* or **saves** the list of matching file names.  You can save to a Lisp variable or a file, or just to memory using no variable.

   Now change your minibuffer input (you are still in the same `C-x C-f` command invocation) to a different dir and file-names pattern, and then hit `C->` to add the new matches to the saved set you created using the first pattern.  Repeat for as many dirs and file patterns as you like.  End with `C-g` if you don't want to visit the files now, or with `RET` if you do.

   To **reuse** *a saved set of file names*, use `C-x C-f` and then hit `C-M-<`.  (To retrieve a persistently saved set, use `C-u` first: `C-u C-M-<`.)  What this does is define the current set of file-name matches to be those in your saved set of names.  Hit `RET` to visit all of them.  Or you can add to or subtract from the set, to open a slightly different set.

   During completion you can also combine sets of candidates: complementing, union, intersection, set difference. There are quick keys bound for such operations.

   You can also define a set for later reuse using Lisp.  An easy way to do this interactively is to use `M-x icicle-candidate-set-define` during file-name completion.  It prompts you for a Lisp sexp that evaluates to a list of file-name strings.
3. Yet another way: In a Dired buffer, mark the files you want there, then use `C-M->` to save them as a set that you can reuse as in #2, above.  Go to another Dired directory, mark files there, and then use `C->` to add them to the set you defined from the first Dired buffer.  And so on.

   You can even collect all of the marked files from a Dired buffer and the marked files in its marked subdirs (or all of the files in its marked subdirs), by using `M-+ C-M->` (and similarly, for `M-+ C->`).

Besides saving a set of file names in a file, as suggested above, you can use an Emacs bookmark.  If you use library [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) then you can easily bookmark sets of files and directories using Dired bookmarks (marks are remembered etc.). You can also ***tag*** files and directories (as bookmarks) with any number of free-form tags.  Each tag defines, in effect, a set of bookmarks.  See the **Bookmark+** doc for more info about these features.

Though it is a separate library from **Bookmark+** (neither requires the other), **Icicles** offers many ways to make use of such **Bookmark+** features, including easily accessing files and dirs that are tagged with particular sets of tags.

This should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), I made [helm-cmd-t](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-cmd-t) specifically for this purpose.  Open issues on github if it's not clear enough how to use it.

Comment: I should also add helm works with "locate" indexed databases.

Comment: OK, thank you... This might be a forbidden question, but should I use Helm or Icicles? I haven't been able to find a resource comparing the two. I'm open to learning a new tool to help me with file and dired management. And I looked for helm tutorials but didn't find much beyond the helm Github wiki.

Comment: It's not forbidden, but I doubt you'll find anyone with enough knowledge in both to answer.  I don't know very much about icicles, but it appears helm has more steam and a more transparent development process.  You can try both and reply with your findings though.